# Is it required to keep space after type cast by Symfony coding standards?

Tags: php, symfony, coding-style

I just couldn't find an answer in [the official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html).
So PHP Code Sniffer says it's required (coding standards package `escapestudios/symfony2-coding-standard`).

Example as it should be:

```
$result = (bool) foo();
```

and vise versa:

```
$result = (bool)foo();
```

Comment: Just FYI: For Symfony coding standard, there is https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer. With `--level=symfony` option.

Comment: @TomášVotruba Thanks for this note.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [it is](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer#usage):

[image]

#### How to Apply It?

- In CodeSniffer, you're looking for `PHP_CodeSniffer\Standards\Generic\Sniffs\Formatting\SpaceAfterCastSniff`
- In PHP-CS-Fixer, it would be `PhpCsFixer\Fixer\CastNotation\CastSpacesFixer`

[image]

Tool used in here is [EasyCodingStandard](https://github.com/Symplify/EasyCodingStandard) - you can [read intro post about it](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/03/combine-power-of-php-code-sniffer-and-php-cs-fixer-in-3-lines/).